# How to use 2 WiFi adapters Win8.1 & Win10, or best alternative

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, gigabit-ethernet

In an attempt to "cut the cord" - reduce the tangle of cables, plus take advantage of higher speeds, I am attempting to use two WiFi cards at the same time on a Win8.1 laptop and a Win10 laptop.

The goal is to have three Windows computers connected, with SSD boot drives in them and with all the libraries stored on a hard drive in the NAS system.

My situation is that I have Ethernet connecting them to a switch (192.168.2.x) that allows them to use Windows mapping in order to access the Windows 7-based NAS server by drive letter.  This subnet also connects through a hardware firewall out to the Internet.

Then also have WiFi access on each to the special subnet (192.168.6.x) which is behind another firewall so the router is only accessible via WiFi - and provides access to data loggers and controls for the solar power station.

The Win8.1 laptop is using an external WiFi adapter, and the Win10 laptop is currently using the internal adapter.  They both act the same - internal vs external seems not to be an issue.

So far, so good.  **Both systems work well with Ethernet for one subnet and WiFi for the other.**  It all works fine.

Until I try to add a second WiFi adapter to bypass the Ethernet cable which is limited to 100 Mbps.  WiFi provides much higher speeds - up to 433 Mbps.

**Getting the same results in both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10; namely, the systems do not seem to be able to tolerate having two WiFi adapters in them.  In both cases the 2nd WiFi adapter acts like it can't see any networks at all.**

Since this is happening to both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 I presume this must be a common issue that someone here knows about.

So the question is in the title:  **How to use 2 WiFi dapters Win8.1 & Win10, or best alternative?**

Comment: For the higher speed side of things, is gigabit networking not an option? It is inexpensive these days. That is 1000Mbps instead of 100 with your current cables or 300Mbps with your new wifi.

Comment: You just put your finger on precisely what I am trying to accomplish.  I have a new router standing by that handles dual-band, and the particular adapters I am trying to use are all 802.11ac-capable.  But rather than complicate the question with all that I simply need to find a way so the computers can handle two Wi-Fi adapters in the first place.  But yes, I am already salivating at the idea of gigabit-level wireless backups.   IF they would tolerate dual adapters.  The control network must be WiFi and completely separate.  The lack of 2 WiFi adapters is hampering my cord-cutting strategy.

Comment: btw, two of the three computers can handle Gigabit Ethernet, now that you mention it.  I guess I should get this router installed and go that direction for the moment.  But this question still stands - why can't they work with two WiFi adapters....  I really do want to eliminate the cables.

Comment: Ah Gigabit WiFi, the dream... For now, what you're thinking of is termed NIC Bonding, which I think is easy on Linux but more complicated on Windows, where you'll need a Windows Server OS. Note NIC Teaming is not necessarily the same if you come across that. I'm afraid I'm not an expert in this area but that might give you a starting point. Ethernet wise, I use powerline adapters with 1200Mbps capability - this means I can get a gigabit Ethernet connection anywhere in the building by plugging in my laptop to a plug socket. Might work for you too, thought it worth mentioning as it avoids wiring

Comment: It certainly is. Sounds like a good plan, just thought I'd link [the powerline adapters](https://rover.ebay.com/rover/0/0/0?mpre=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.co.uk%2Fulk%2Fitm%2F253190528889) I use, better prices can be found. My system identifies those as providing a gigabit connection but do note that using electrical wiring as networking cabling can hamper speeds significantly; I use mine for internet connectivity so as long as I get 300Mbps speeds I don't notice any impact from the powerline units. Do make sure you use Cat 5e or above patch cables too! All the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I found that Windows 8.1 simply will not do it.

But I found that it could tolerate a USB Gigabit adapter, so now all three computers have Gigabit networking.  I bought a Linksys EA6900 Gigabit router for $25 and some CAT6 cables and now the Windows computers are talking to each other just fine.

Backups are running just fine and fast to the Win7-based NAS.

Special thanks to all who commented on the question.  The comments are where I found the answer.  I am very grateful.

It is all running like it is all in a single system, now, regardless of which keyboard I am at.